# App is crashing at launch

Tags: java, android

Following is the MainActivity of a simple SQLite example. The app is crashing at launch. Following is the error(in bold):

```
11-10 10:40:41.243 1773-1773/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-10 10:40:41.286 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database V/Theme: ColorMode:com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database is false
11-10 10:40:41.328 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.473 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.513 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.553 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.593 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.631 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.669 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.706 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.747 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.788 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.836 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 10:40:41.837 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database-1/lib/arm64
11-10 10:40:41.840 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-10 10:40:41.843 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database I/Instrumentation: android.app.Application@103d181 onCreate begin
11-10 10:40:41.843 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database I/Instrumentation: android.app.Application@103d181 onCreate in 0ms
11-10 10:40:41.900 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-10 10:40:42.003 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 10:40:42.003 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database, PID: 1773
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View$OnLongClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View$OnLongClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                **at com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database.MainActivity.displayAllRecords(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                                                at com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)**
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-10 10:40:42.005 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
11-10 10:40:44.108 1773-1773/com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1773 SIG: 9
```

Following is the code for the MainActivity:

```
package com.mytestfyp.ahmed.database;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Button btnAddNewRecord;
    SQLiteHelper sQLiteHelper;

    android.widget.LinearLayout parentLayout;
    LinearLayout layoutDisplayPeople;

    TextView tvNoRecordsFound;
    private String rowID = null;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private class Holder
    {
        TextView tvFullName;
        String name;
        String age;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getAllWidgets();
        sQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
        bindWidgetsWithEvent();
        displayAllRecords();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            //firstname & lastname
            String name = data.getStringExtra(Constants.NAME);
            String age = data.getStringExtra(Constants.AGE);

            ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
            contact.setName(name);
            contact.setAge(age);

            if (requestCode == Constants.ADD_RECORD)
            {
                sQLiteHelper.insertRecord(contact);
            }

            else if (requestCode == Constants.UPDATE_RECORD)
            {
                contact.setID(rowID);
                sQLiteHelper.updateRecord(contact);
            }

            displayAllRecords();

        }
    }

    private void getAllWidgets()
    {
        btnAddNewRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewRecord);
        parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        tvNoRecordsFound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoRecordsFound);
    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithEvent()
    {
        btnAddNewRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onAddRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    private void onAddRecord()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TableManipulationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.DML_TYPE, Constants.ADD_RECORD);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.ADD_RECORD);
    }

    private void onUpdateRecord(String name, String age)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TableManipulationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.NAME, name);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.AGE, age);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.DML_TYPE, Constants.UPDATE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.UPDATE_RECORD);
    }

    private void displayAllRecords()
    {
        LinearLayout inflateParentView;
        parentLayout.removeAllViews();

        ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts = sQLiteHelper.getAllRecords();

        if (contacts.size() > 0)
        {
            tvNoRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ContactModel contactModel;

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
            {
                contactModel = contacts.get(i);

                final Holder holder = new Holder();
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.inflate_record, null);
                inflateParentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);
                holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);

                view.setTag(contactModel.getID());
                holder.name = contactModel.getName();
                holder.age = contactModel.getAge();

                String personData = holder.name + " " +holder.age;
                holder.tvFullName.setText(personData);

                final CharSequence[] items = {Constants.UPDATE, Constants.DELETE};

                inflateParentView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                if (which == 0)
                                {
                                    rowID = view.getTag().toString();
                                    onUpdateRecord(holder.name, holder.age);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialogOK = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    deleteDialogOK.setTitle("Delete Person ?");

                                    deleteDialogOK.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                        {
                                            ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
                                            contact.setID(view.getTag().toString());
                                            sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(contact);
                                            displayAllRecords();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    deleteDialogOK.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                        {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    deleteDialogOK.show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                parentLayout.addView(view);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            tvNoRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Following are the related XMLs:

activitymain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutDisplayPeople"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/people"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNoRecordsFound"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/nrf"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddNewRecord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_blue"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

inflate_record.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inflateParentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/color_grey"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you debuged  your code and checked exact which line is causing crash.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inflateParentView is null because its not instantiated.Calling findViewById() in activity will find the id in the particular activity layout.You need to find the view from the custom layout.So change this line.

```
inflateParentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);
```

to

```
inflateParentView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);
```

Comment: Your most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your app crashes because you get NullPointerException when trying to invoke `setOnLongClickListener()` on **NULL** inflateParentView. Make sure that view is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`inflateParentView = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);`.

You are getting `NullPointerException` for `inflateParentView`. That's because you are trying to find the view from activity layout and not from inflated view. Hope it helps :)